# Jenkins - warnings-ng-plugin integration with android lint report

Tags: jenkins

I have generated lint results as XML from the build process in the Jenkins with the following gradle script. Now I would like to generate report by using warning-ng-plugin. 'warning-ng-plugin' is already installed in the Jenkins. I am already generating a nice report for my java code base with warning-ng-plugin, but I am not sure what kind of parser or tools I need to specify for android code base in the Jenkinsfile.  I see the XML file generated in the lint/reports/main.xml.

---- build.gradle

```
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
        xmlOutput file("lint/reports/main.xml")
        warningsAsErrors true
        xmlReport true
    }
```

-- Jenkinsfile

```
stage('Post') {
    junit 'bundles/*/generated/test-reports/test/TEST-*.xml'
    junit 'android/*/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'

    recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tools: [java(), pmdParser(pattern: '**/pmd/reports/main.xml')]
    recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tools: [java(), android(pattern: '**/lint/reports/main.xml')]
```

}

Please let me know how to generate report out of the android lint in the Jenkins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tools: [androidLintParser(pattern: '**/lint-results-*.xml')]
```

So try using `androidLintParser` instead of `android`.